# What is the idle period before Cloud Function will cold start again upon invoking?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

On average I will be calling my cloud function every minute but occasionally there will be longer non-active periods up to 20 minutes. But I still want to avoid cold starts.

Is there documented or empirical value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 30 minutes in mind, but it's not documented. For Cloud Run, it's usually 15 minutes and it's [documented](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#idle).

However, you can't rely on that. Most of the time, the regular time are used, but sometime it could be shorter if there is crash or maintenance required on the underlying infrastructure.

In addition, those configuration can be change at any time by Google Cloud and without notice. It's serverless; don't rely on the server behavior, you don't manage the servers

Comment: Please do not use the 'serverless' misnomer. There is no such thing as 'serverless'.

Comment: "Don't-worry-about-servers-config-and-pathing", in short, serverless, but there are still servers, but you don't manage them!